# Can not launch JavaFx application from jar file. Class not found exception

Tags: java, dependency-injection, provider, classnotfound

I want to launch my java fx application from jar, but I catch the following error:

Exception in Application start method

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/inject/Provider
        at ua.makovskyi.poslike.core.App.initAppComponent(App.java:52)
        at ua.makovskyi.poslike.core.App.start(App.java:41)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.inject.Provider
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I use dagger2 for dependecy injection, and inside start() method my application component is initializing.
Very strange, 'cause I've included javax.inject dependecy in pom file.
Language level - 8. JDK/JRE version 1.8.0_192. Artifact - java fx application.

**[EDITED]**
My pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>Poslike</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.saxsys</groupId>
            <artifactId>mvvmfx</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.saxsys</groupId>
            <artifactId>mvvmfx-validation</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.saxsys</groupId>
            <artifactId>mvvmfx-utils</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava2</groupId>
            <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.14-RC1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava2</groupId>
            <artifactId>rxjavafx</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>adapter-rxjava2</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>converter-gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>dagger</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.datafx</groupId>
            <artifactId>datafx</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>jempbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmpbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>preflight</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ralfstuckert.pdfbox-layout</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox2-layout</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
                            <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
                            <version>2.16</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Could you please show your `pom.xml` file?

Comment: @AleksandrPodkutin already attached

Comment: Thanks! @DenisMakovsky

Comment: (unrelated to your problem) PDFBox is now at 2.0.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be sure that your container is providing dependency `javax.inject`
or simply remove `<scope>provided</scope>`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```

Also it will be better to explicitly set the `source` and `target` properties for the `maven-compiler-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And if you want to run your application with this command `java -jar MyApp.jar` you need to provide all dependencies in the -cp flag or inside of the jar.

To package your jar with the whole list of dependencies, you can use `maven-assembly-plugin`, like this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
        <manifest>
            <mainClass>
                !!!com.package.path.ClassWithMainMethodName!!!
            </mainClass>
        </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: It does not help

Comment: still nothing =(

Comment: ClassNotFound javax.inject.Provider. But how could it be?

Comment: How and I expected, implementation of my interface AppComponent - DaggerAppComponent has not been generated. Build failed

Comment: Commented <repositories> block, after that performed mvb clean, but this operation has not complete successfully, 'cause I use 8 language level, and maven all time after any changes try to set 1.5 language level. After that rebuilded jar, tried to launch, and catched same exception. I have no any idea what it could be

Comment: But now mvn clean task performs successfully

Comment: mvn clean compile

Comment: I've performed successfully command mvn clean compile.But I could not launch app from jar( Catched same ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: java -jar MyApp.jar

Comment: or java[w] -jar MyApp.jar com.package.App

Comment: Ok, now I think we know the root cause. There is no dependencies in your `MyApp.jar` you need to use `maven-assembly-plugin` to package your application and whole list of dependencies inside of your jar. I've added it to the answer. @DenisMakovsky

Comment: I've found temporary solution: i've excecuted maven command maven assembly:directory and I've got appname_jar_with_dependecies.jar in target folder and folder with all classes inside(non project files, mean 3-rd part artifacts also included here). I've ran this with java -jar name.jar and oh God, this is working. By I think it is non best solution

Comment: @DenisMakovsky :) you can check my previous comment 12h ago, I'v proposed the same. It depends what you want to achieve. If you want to just write a demo application it should be enough.